# Choosing between Playmaker or Game Creator for a non-coder

Tags: unity, game-design

The Unity Asset Store is having a huge sale today and saw these two featured.

I'm trying to create a one-level third-person horde mode shooter. It would spawn in at least 3 different enemy types that I can shoot at in a set amount of waves. I would like to know which one can easily make this for me as a non-coder. AI doesn't need to be that extensive just monsters chasing after the Player is enough.

Not to say too much, I just need this much to green light something so I would like to hear your advise

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, but we generally don't give technology recommendations because they are too much based on personal opinions. If you want some opinions about those assets, then you unfortunately have to look for comments on them elsewhere.

Comment: And a good start would be a review of said assets. Another point to take into consideration is the amount of tutorials available.

Comment: Please do not post the same question multiple times.

Comment: As context, OP originally posted this on the Blender SE where it was (rightfully) closed as off topic & given the suggestion to post here. That said, for any given Stack Exchange, it's the user's responsibility check that stack's guidelines for questions. If it was closed here once already, reposting isn't going to change that. If you have questions about why it's off topic here or how we can help, I encourage you to ask via the comments or on the [GDSE meta](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: no such thing as a non-coder. If you want to make a game, learn to code.

Comment: yeah, coding is definitely the route to go for making games. It's actually not really that hard to learn, it just looks daunting at first.